# how to convert the string to arabic language in swift

Tags: ios, swift, string

Hi all I am new to swift, I am parsing Data from JSon and show into the tableview it's working fine, In Json some string are into the Arabic language.like this

```
[{"ID":"1","EmpName":"أحمد زكي","CustName":"Yasser","Status":"sold","Item_ID":"1","Date":"\/Date(1494147367000)\/"}]
```

when I parse this Json its coming like this 
 EmpName = "\U0623\U062d\U0645\U062f \U0632\U0643\U064a";

this is the my parsing code

```
func jsonparse()
{
    let url = URL(string: "http://mobile.net/orders?userid=1")
    Alamofire.request(url!, method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON(completionHandler:
        {
            response in
            print(response.result.value as Any)
            let JsonData = response.result.value as! [[String:Any]]
            for jsonvalues in JsonData
            {
                self.Trans_data.append(Trans_userInfo.init(CustName:(jsonvalues["CustName"] as! String) , Date:(jsonvalues["Date"] as! String) , EmpName: (jsonvalues["EmpName"] as! String), ID: jsonvalues["CustName"] as? Int , Item_ID: (jsonvalues["Item_ID"] as! String) , Status: jsonvalues["Status"] as? String ))
            }
            self.reload_Data()
    }).resume()
   }
```

how can I show the EmpName in arabic language

Comment: can you add the code of your parsing>

Comment: Can you check in this line `Alamofire.request(url!, method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)` in `JSONEncoding` what other options are available

Comment: @sanjaykmwt its working bro thank you for ur replay

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter what you see on console, they are `Encoded` values but when you show it on a label it will come in `Arabic` only.

Also don't force unwrap values use `guard let / if let` :

```
guard let custName = jsonvalues["CustName"] as? String, let date = jsonvalues["Date"] as? String, let empName as? String, let custName = as? Int, let itemId = jsonvalues["Item_ID"] as? String, let status = jsonvalues["Status"] as? String else {
    print("Problem in fetching values")
    return
}
self.Trans_data.append(Trans_userInfo.init(CustName: custName , Date: date, EmpName: empName, ID: custName , Item_ID: itemId, Status: status ))
```

Comment: @ARAV Use guard let from now on, you will save a lot of crashes.